# How to improve SQL Query in LARAVEL?

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I'm working on SQL. My database has so many entries that reason query is taking too much time. Is there any solution to improve my query performance?

I use many `group by` and `sum` of value.

My Query:

```
SELECT airplay_songs.song_uuid, 
       airplay_songs.song_isrc, 
       Sum(airplay_songs.play_count) AS play_count 
FROM   artist_music 
       INNER JOIN airplay_songs 
               ON artist_music.uuid = airplay_songs.song_uuid 
                  AND artist_music.isrc = airplay_songs.song_isrc 
WHERE  airplay_songs.aired_at > 2020 - 12 - 21 
       AND airplay_songs.aired_at < 2020 - 12 - 28 
GROUP  BY airplay_songs.song_uuid, 
          airplay_songs.song_isrc 
ORDER  BY play_count DESC 
LIMIT  400
```

Comment: You are using the `GROUP BY` and also using the `DISTINCT`. You can remove the `DISTINCT` as it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks For Comment Still Getting too much load any Other solution @Popeye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you can write the query as:

```
select aps.song_uuid, aps.song_isrc, sum(aps.play_count) as play_count
from airplay_songs aps
where aps.aired_at > '2020-12-21' and aps.aired_at < '2020-12-28'
group by aps.song_uuid, aps.song_isrc
order by sum(play_count) desc
limit 400;
```

There are three changes:

- The dates have single quotes.
- The table `artist_music` does not appear to be used in the query, so it is removed.
- The `order by` is clear that it refers to the `sum(play_count)`.

Then for this query, you want an index on `airplay_songs(aired_at, song_uid, song_isrc, play_count)`.

Comment: Thanks For answer but I need join with artist_music Table

Comment: @G1latest . . . You can include the `JOIN`, but nothing from that table is used in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Are your tables indexed? I had a query that took around ~40s and dropped to 1.2s after indexing. I had 3 joins and worked with 50k+ data.

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) for more about indexing.

Edit: typo

Comment: i added index. and i have 300k+ data